# Android Studio не может взять файлы из drawable

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable

Android Studio не может найти изображения и выдает ошибку
`AAPT: error: resource drawable/shape_circle (aka ru.l4legenda.ktk45:drawable/shape_circle) not found.`

До этого все работало, но в какой-то момент появился этот баг.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуйте: закройте AS удалите в проекте папки build app/build

Comment: что помешало отрезать лишнее от изображения, юный падаван?

Comment: Удаление build не помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка просто нелепая, в одном из xml файлов было дважды
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`
И поэтому выдавало ошибку во все файлы